# How can I investigate limit at infinity with asymptotic series?

Tags: asymptotics

I have the following function $h_1(x)$:

```
h1[x : _] = (1/(8 a))Sech[a x]^2 (-12 a^3 + 8 a d + 8 a c x + 96 a^3 Log[Cosh[a x]] + 
  12 a^3 Cosh[3 a x] Sech[a x] + 
  c Sech[a x] Sinh[
  3 a x] - (c + 4 a^2 (4 b + x (12 a^2 + 2 d - 12 a^3 x + c x)) + 
  96 a^4 x (-Log[1 + E^(-2 a x)] + Log[Cosh[a x]]) + 
  48 a^3 PolyLog[2, -E^(-2 a x)]) Tanh[a x])
```

I want to choose $b$, $c$ and $d$ to make $h_1$ go to zero at infinity.

Is there a way to do this with asymptotic series in Mathematica?

Comment: @user64494, please thoroughly and carefully read [instructions for editing posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Especially pay attention to: __Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged__.

Comment: @Domen:  Did you pay your attention to "To fix grammatical or spelling mistakes"? I did.

Comment: @user64494, again: _Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged ... correcting **all problems** that you observe_. And also, you've been warned before that "How to ..." should not end with a question mark.

Comment: @Domen: Sorry, there is no description of "Tiny, trivial edits" in the instruction. I am sure that the edit of grammar mistakes in titles makes forum better. BTW, all the titles in the instruction end with a question mark.

Answer (score 4):

Here a solution using `Asymptotic`

```
h[x_] := (1/(8 a)) Sech[a x]^2 (-12 a^3 + 8 a d + 8 a c x + 
    96 a^3 Log[Cosh[a x]] + 12 a^3 Cosh[3 a x] Sech[a x] + 
    c Sech[a x] Sinh[
      3 a x] - (c + 4 a^2 (4 b + x (12 a^2 + 2 d - 12 a^3 x + c x)) + 
       96 a^4 x (-Log[1 + E^(-2 a x)] + Log[Cosh[a x]]) + 
       48 a^3 PolyLog[2, -E^(-2 a x)]) Tanh[a x])
```

find asymptote

```
asy = Asymptotic[h[x], x -> Infinity] (*ConditionalExpression[6 a^2 + c/(2 a), (b | c | d) \[Element] Reals && a > 0]*)
```

should be zero

```
solc = Solve[asy[[1]] == 0, c][[1]] (* {c -> -12 a^3} *)
```

solution `h[x]`

```
h[x]/.solc//Simplify (* depends on parameter `a>0, b,d`)
```

[image]

higher order approximations follow step by step

```
asy2 = Asymptotic[h[x] /. solc, x -> Infinity ] // Simplify
(* ConditionalExpression[4 a E^(-2 a x)x (-d + 6 a^2 (-1 + Log[4])),(b | d) \[Element] Reals && a > 0] *)

h[x] /. solc /. d -> 6 a^2 (-1 + Log[4]) // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I found the same condition by hand with help of Mathematica. The first step was `Expand[(TrigToExp[(1/(8 a)) Sech[a x]^2 (-12 a^3 + 8 a d + 8 a c x + 
        96 a^3 Log[Cosh[a x]] + 12 a^3 Cosh[3 a x] Sech[a x] + 
        c Sech[a x] Sinh[
          3 a x] - (c + 
           4 a^2 (4 b + x (12 a^2 + 2 d - 12 a^3 x + c x)) + 
           96 a^4 x (-Log[1 + E^(-2 a x)] + Log[Cosh[a x]]) + 
           48 a^3 PolyLog[2, -E^(-2 a x)]) Tanh[a x])] /. {Exp[-a*x] ->
       0, Exp[-2*a*x] -> 0, Exp[-3*a*x] -> 0}) /. 
  Log[E^(a x)/2] -> a*x - Log[2]]`.

Comment: @simon Hope it helps! You are welcome!

Comment: Expand[(TrigToExp[h1[x]] /. {Exc = -12 a^3p[-a*x] -> 0, Exp[-2*a*x] -> 0, 
     Exp[-3*a*x] -> 0}) /. Log[E^(a x)/2] -> a*x - Log[2]]   Thank you so                                                    c = -12 a^3         but the following still draws an echo not a limit of 0                                         Evaluate[Limit[h1[x], x -> Infinity]]

Comment: Sorry Ulrich;  I can't get your code to really so anything. Could be my v9 or misunderstanding . Can you show the output please for the first 2 commands, please

Comment: @simon See the comments of the first  two commands. I'm unsure whether `Asymptotic` is known in v9

Comment: @simon: Did you pay you attention to the words "The first step was ..." in my comment?

Comment: Yes 64494 yours worked immediately and gave me the answer clearly, which has been a  great assistance to me. Thanks a million

Comment: @64494 I got around to understanding what you did. Clever I never would have found that or been able to compose it. Sorry D giving you a hard time. You were great help. Allowed me to complete the entire work.